# iOS : GoogleDrive API (API Secret and ID)

Tags: ios, google-drive-api

I have a public read-only GoogleDrive URL.
I want to code in such a way that I allow the app users to read the documents (readonly)

I don't want the users to login with their Google Account and I am sharing the files via a public link. For this do I need to use a App ID, App secret etc. ?

And, also please tell me how can I list all the files?
The below code works only on API Secret authentications.
Please help

```
GTLServiceDrive *drive = ...; NSString *parentId = @"root";

GTLQueryDrive *query = [GTLQueryDrive queryForFilesList]; query.q = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"'%@' in parents", parentId; [drive executeQuery:query completionHandler:^(GTLServiceTicket *ticket,
                                              GTLDriveFileList *files,
                                              NSError *error) {   if (error == nil) {
    NSLog(@"Have results");
    // Iterate over files.items array   } else {
    NSLog(@"An error occurred: %@", error);   } }];
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the documentation here for this. 
https://code.google.com/p/google-api-objectivec-client/wiki/Introduction#Result_Pages